# EnvironmentError: [WinError 123] during pandas installation

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting the following error message while trying to do a pip install pandas:

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '"C:'

I've tried all the other solutions I've found but nothing is working for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any reply based on your poor description of the problem is pure guesswork, e.g. what's the path to your Python interpreter and do you have any blanks in your username?

Comment: 'c:\users\ryan's computer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe

Answer (score 1):

`ryan's computer` is actually your user name? This is asking for trouble. Change it, and you'll be able to install any package w/o any problems.